# Bash - How to count occurences in a column of a .csv file (without awk)

Tags: bash

recently i've started to learn bash scripting and im wondering how i can count occurences in a column of a .csv file, the file is structured like this:

```
    DAYS,SOMEVALUE,SOMEVALUE
    sunday,something,something
    monday,something,something
    wednesday,something,something
    sunday,something,something
    monday,something,something
```

so my question is: how can i count each time every value of first column (days) appear? In this case the outputs must be:

```
    Sunday : 2
    Monday : 2
    Wednesday: 1
```

The first column is named DAYS, so the script has to not take care of the single value DAYS, DAYS is just a way to identify the column.

if possible i want to see a solution without the awk command and without phyton ecc..

Thx guys and sorry for my bad English

Edit: I thought to do this:

```
    count="$( cat "${FILE}" | grep -c "OCCURENCE")"
    echo "OCCURENCE": ${count}
```

Where OCCURENCE is the single values (sunday,monday...)
But this solution is not automatic, i need to make a list of single occurences in the first column of .csv file and put each one on an array and then count each one with the code i written before. I need some help to do this thx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
cut -f1 -d, test.csv | tail -n +2 | sort | uniq -c
```

This gets you this far:

```
  2 monday
  2 sunday
  1 wednesday
```

To get your format (`Sunday : 1`), I think `awk` would be an easy and clear way (something like `awk '{print $2 " : " $1}'`, but if you really really must, here's a complete non-awk version:

```
cut -f1 -d, test.csv | uniq -c | tail -n +2 | while read line; do words=($line); echo ${words[1]} : ${words[0]}; done
```

Comment: Thx this is what i want :) And if i want to display only an accourence choosen by keyboard? for example i want only to see the number of "monday" occurance

Comment: In that case I'd say adding ` | grep monday` to the command would be the best option

Comment: There's no need to run in loop, as the count is already there. Instead pipe it to *sed* to switch the columns around. In that case you could use: `echo ' 82317 TSLA' | sed -E 's/^[[:space:]]+([0-9]+) (.+)$/\2 : \1/g'`. This would give you: `TSLA : 82317`, which is probably also faster for large files. Adjust to your own use case.

Answer (score 2):

A variation of @sneep's answer that uses `sed` to format the result:

```
cut -f1 -d, /tmp/data  | tail -n +2 | sort | uniq -c | sed 's|^ *\([0-9]*\) \(.*\)|\u\2: \1|g'
```

Output:

```
Monday: 2
Sunday: 2
Wednesday: 1
```

The `sed` is matching:

- `^ *`: Beginning of line and then any number of spaces
- `\([0-9]*\)`: Any number of numbers (storing them in a group \1)
- : A single space
- `\(.*\)`: Any character until the end, storing it in group \2

And replaces the match with:

- `\u\2`: Second group, capitalizing first character
- `: \1`: Colon, space and the first group

Comment: A nice solution, also capitalizing the Days / words.